# Why is jQuery ignoring the contents of my div?

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I have a simple toggle for a div attached to a chekbox.

```
$('#step2').hide();

$('#toggle-check').click(function(){

$('#step2').fadeToggle();

})
```

Why won't .hide(); select my contents of #step2 ? It's currently a list of table data, and it isnt hiding it. I'll end my div early and it will work.

```
<tr>
<th></th>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

It's currently adding my #step2 div above all my table data, so I feel it might be a CSS styling issue?

Comment: Where is `#step2` and what does it contain? Can you post the relevant parts of the code?

Comment: #step2 is wrapped around the above table structure i've given. Giving each row a class of hide and calling it in jquery works, but it's messy, no?

Comment: Is there a `table` element around the markup you've given too (inside the `div`)? If not, it's not valid.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that about jQuery. Thanks :)

Comment: It's not about jQuery, it's about HTML. If the HTML is invalid, you have no idea what the browser will do to try and fix it, and then jQuery won't know what to do either because all the markup has changed.

Comment: Well technically it is about jQuery, as it won't work with invalid HTML. I thought it would select whatever the div was wrapped around, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wrapping your div#step2 around the table row, it won't work because it isn't proper markup. You should wrap it around the entire table.
If you want to keep parts of the table, you should structure it differently.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your code is not executed when the document is ready. This means that it might execute if your page is very short, but not if the entire table is not yet parsed.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(
{
    $('#step2').hide();

    $('#toggle-check').click(function()
    {
        $('#step2').fadeToggle();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your questions , i cant say much.

and also you missed a semi colon here

```
$('#toggle-check').click(function(){

$('#step2').fadeToggle();

})
```

try wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){});` and add a semi colon

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#step2').hide();

$('#toggle-check').click(function(){

$('#step2').fadeToggle();

});

});
```